# Pandas - Do I have to convert objects in float/int in order to sum them?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am doing my very first project with Pandas and this is the data frame I currently have:
[click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKJ8o.png)
I need to calculate the percentage of bachelor degrees, which I read is done by dividing the value by the sum of all the values and then multiplying the sum by 100.
Now, I need to sum all the bachelor degrees and all the rest of the educational values.
My question is, when I have objects as values, in order to sum them, do I have to convert them in float/int necessarly?

I tried to use the .count() function, which actually counts all the values, but I feel like this is not the best/preferred method:

```
bachelor_number = bachelor_df['education'].count()
total_number = demographic_data_df['education'].count()
bachelor_percentage = (bachelor_number * 100) / (total_number)
print('The percentage of people who have a degree is {}%'.format(round(bachelor_percentage, 1)))
```

Any advice for a newbie would be super appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If they are not numeric, then you will be using a different overload function. Simple example `'a' + 'b'` produces `'ab'`. Now assume you had `'1' +'3'` this will give `'13'` But is that what you want? eg if you had lists `sum([[1],[2]], [])` will result in `[1,2]` is that what you want? So the objective will determine as to whether the data need be of a particular type

Answer (score 0):

Use the [value counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) function instead. Something like
`bachelor_df['education'].value_counts()` should give you what you want.